# Fail to upload to sonatype with sbt 0.13 with xsbt-gpg-plugin unresolved dependency: com.jsuereth#xsbt-gpg-plugin;0.6

Tags: scala, sbt

my `plugins.sbt` has this:

```
logLevel := Level.Warn

addSbtPlugin("com.earldouglas" % "xsbt-web-plugin" % "1.0.0")

resolvers += Resolver.url("sbt-plugin-releases", new URL("http://scalasbt.artifactoryonline.com/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases")) (Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)

addSbtPlugin("com.jsuereth" % "xsbt-gpg-plugin" % "0.6")
```

when i run `sbt publish` i get:

> [warn] ==== sbt-plugin-releases: tried [warn]
>   http://scalasbt.artifactoryonline.com/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.jsuereth/xsbt-gpg-plugin/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/0.6/ivys/ivy.xml
>   [warn]    :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: [warn]   ::
>   UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         :: [warn]
>     :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: [warn]   ::
>   com.jsuereth#xsbt-gpg-plugin;0.6: not found [warn]
>     :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: [warn]  [warn]   Note:
>   Some unresolved dependencies have extra attributes.  Check that these
>   dependencies exist with the requested attributes. [warn]
>         com.jsuereth:xsbt-gpg-plugin:0.6 (sbtVersion=0.13,
>   scalaVersion=2.10) [warn]  **sbt.ResolveException: unresolved
>   dependency: com.jsuereth#xsbt-gpg-plugin;0.6: not found**     at
>   sbt.IvyActions$.sbt$IvyActions$$resolve(IvyActions.scala:217)     at
>   sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$update$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:126)

So I tried updating the `addSbtPlugin` to be:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.jsuereth" % "xsbt-gpg-plugin" % "0.6",
  sbtVersion = "0.12",    // SBT version
  scalaVersion = "2.9.2" )
```

Now I get

```
[warn] The global sbt directory is now versioned and is located at /home//.sbt/0.13.
[warn]   You are seeing this warning because there is global configuration in /home//.sbt but not in /home//.sbt/0.13.
[warn]   The global sbt directory may be changed via the sbt.global.base system property.
[info] Loading project definition from /home//dev/projects/myproj/project
[warn] Multiple resolvers having different access mechanism configured with same name 'sbt-plugin-releases'. To avoid conflict, Remove duplicate project resolvers (`resolvers`) or rename publishing resolver (`publishTo`).
**java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sbt/Scoped$ListSetting**
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
```

anyway to fix it please?
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure, but I think you use a rather old version of that plugin?

I use the following with latest **sbt 0.13.6**. I have this globally installed in `~/.sbt/0.13/plugins/build.sbt`:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-pgp" % "0.8.1") // sign Sonatype artifacts
```

I also left my credentials in `~/.sbt/0.13/sonatype.sbt`:

```
credentials += Credentials("Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager",
                           "oss.sonatype.org",
                           "user-name", "pass-word")
```

This way I can do `sbt publish-signed`.

---

[Here is the plugin documentation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-pgp/index.html). (As you can see, there is already an even newer version available)